# iOs - Send Status without using UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, sdk

In SDK for iOS, there is a way to send a status without open UIWebView?
Maybe a url with post body,
I really need a way to send without uiwebview form.

Thanks

Comment: I had an answer but deleted it because it wasn't appropriate for the question.  The original poster added a (now deleted) command that says: "i need a way to send text and/or photo and/or link".  -1 to the question for being unclear.

Comment: When you say send a status... do you mean to FB or just send some text to some backend?

Comment: send some text to some backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for doing it regarding Facebook:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:facebookClient.accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
[params setObject:@"New status" forKey:@"message"];
[facebookClient requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
[params release];
```

Comment: No, i need that dont open the window "Connect to Facebook" to share, just to login

Comment: Are you paying attention to the actual method I wrote? it doesn't open the UIWebView. -requestWithGraphPath: works WITHOUT (you hear, WITHOUT) the UI. Anyway, you can log in sans the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself- just use an NSURLConnection POST form to send data to a script on your server, i.e.

```
        NSString *formContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@", someName];
        NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com/submit.php"];
        NSMutableURLRequest* urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[formContent dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest 
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                                   NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]); //script return
                               }];
```